# Cannot perform ajax request using Cordova Background fetch plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have trouble getting ajax request to execute using Cordova Background fetch plugin,

Background fetch plugin:
https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-fetch

angular-azure-mobile-service:
https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-azure-mobile-service

My code:

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function () {

            //iOS Background Fetch
            if (ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {

                var Fetcher = window.BackgroundFetch;

                // Your background-fetch handler.
                var fetchCallback = function () {

                    Azureservice.invokeApi('myAPI', {
                        method: 'post',
                        body: {
                            createdby: $scope.userid
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function (count) {

                        cordova.plugins.notification.badge.set(count);

                        Fetcher.finish();

                    }, function (err) {

                    });

                }
                var failureCallback = function () {
                    console.log('- BackgroundFetch failed');
                };
                Fetcher.configure(fetchCallback, failureCallback, {
                    stopOnTerminate: false  // <-- false is default
                });
            }


});
```

What should I do to get it to work?

Comment: What's the error? Did you install the whitelist plugin?

Comment: Sorry I cannot see the log because I'm using Visual Studio Cordova Local Device Build. And I don't have a whitelist plugin, but the api call works if the app is open.

Comment: I have a similar problem.. did you manage to get it working in the end?